# Image size - how to?

Tags: android

I just want to make a simple image view but when I run that app the unnecessary white background comes. I don't want to need that part. any solution.

[image: the white part unecessary]

and here is my xml file for that image view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/pot1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: check my below ans

Comment: What do you want in place of the white background?

Answer (score 1):

In code use -

```
imgview.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

Or in xml Image view -

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Comment: if i do that then i lost my width part of that image

Answer (score 0):

remove the `gravity` attribute if you want to make it stick to the top of screen or add scaleType attribute `fitCenter`, `cropCenter` or `fitXY` if you want to make it fill the screen.